# How to convert a vector to a matrix in R starting from the bottom to top

Tags: r

I have a vector `x = c(1,2,3,1,2,0,1,0,0)`. I want to convert it to a matrix starting from the bottom to the top. That is, I need to fill out the entries of the matrix starting from the last entry of each column.

I tried the following:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,1,2,0,1,0,0) 
M2 <- matrix(x, 3, 3) 
M2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    0
[3,]    3    0    0
```

However, I need it as follows:

```
M2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    0    0
[2,]    2    2    0
[3,]    1    1    1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use `apply` and the `rev` function:

```
apply(M2, 2, rev)

    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    0    0
[2,]    2    2    0
[3,]    1    1    1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
> x=c(1,2,3,1,2,0,1,0,0)
> m=matrix(x,3,3);m[nrow(m):1,]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    0    0
[2,]    2    2    0
[3,]    1    1    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Operating directly on `x`:

```
y = x[seq_along(x) + rep_len(c(2, 0, -2), length(x))]
matrix(y, 3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    0    0
[2,]    2    2    0
[3,]    1    1    1
```